# Inhomogeneous boundary conditions for pseduospectral method of the heat equation

Tags: partial-differential-equations, numerical-methods, heat-equation

I would like to numerically solve the 1D heat equation

$$
\frac{\partial T}{\partial t} = \alpha \frac{\partial^{2} T}{\partial x^{2}}
$$

using a pseudospectral (i.e., collocation) method with inhomogeneous Dirichlet boundary conditions. I am aware that this equation has an analytical solution. It is a proxy for a different PDE (a phase-field model for a materials problem) that is not so easily solved (but this is a MWE). I recall that one can do Dirichlet conditions with either a sine or cosine basis (I cannot remember which off-hand). Do they allow for inhomogeneous conditions, or do I need to use something more complex (like a Chebyshev basis)? References would be much appreciated.

Comment: If the equation is linear, you can subtract off a function that satisfies the inhomogeneous boundary conditions to obtain the same linear equation with homogeous boundary conditions and a source term and the spectral methods can be easily applied

Comment: Yeah, perhaps this wasn't clear from the question, but the actual PDE that I am working with is nonlinear (couple Navier-Stokes and non-linear diffusion equation), so I really just care about what can be done with the numerical method.